# Grouping SUPPLY in Eagle

Tags: pcb, schematics, eaglecad, review

I'm designing my first schematic in Eagle, with the aim of getting some PCBs produced.
Been perfboarding for a while, but new to using Eagle.

I've designed a schematic:

[image]

I know it's kind of messy, but as far as I can tell everything is matched up. Now you can probably see more than one V+ pads. The one on the far left and the one on pin 4 of the IC are V+, and that middle top one is actually VA.
When I generate the board, it gives me a pad for every instance of it, instead of just one. Is there a way round this? You can probably make out the red hatching on the bottom right two pads on the board here (power and ground)

[image]

Any help or even feedback on my schematic appreciated!

Comment: I don't know Eagle, but most schematic capture tools will need you to label two nets with different names if you don't want them connected to each other.

Comment: I do want them to connect to each other, and both nets are called V+, but it gives me two pads to place on the board instead of one.

Comment: You have to use other supply symbols which do not produce a pad. The ones which resemble arrows do not. Oh, and fix R4 and run an ERC before starting the layout phase.

Comment: Eagle Supply symbols don't give a pad on the PCB editor. It may be that you placed two "test-points" or something like that, therefore have 2 pads.

Comment: Friendly advice : don't use the auto router

Comment: I've noticed in the library there are two options for supply, +9V and +9V(T). The T one has a pad in the preview, the other doesn't. Could this be it?

Comment: Probably, try changing the component, the pads should disappear. Then in the PCB editor place a via with the desired size and shape and change its net. (Or just keep one of the pads)

Comment: You should use a supply symbol, I think you are using something else like a named pad.

Comment: Would T stand for Terminal/Terminate? I've used a bunch of the non-Ts and one Terminal, about to run a board so I'll see what we get.

Comment: You have R9 connected between two of these locations. What do you expect it to do if it's connected to the same net on both sides?

Comment: As mentioned above - That one over on the left is VR not V+, I just have the labels hidden.

Comment: Check with your board manufacturer on minimum trace / space size, your traces look pretty narrow.